# Alpha background replaced by white background in a dataGridView (first data filling)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, png, alpha

I'm using a dataGridView to show a list of task and a delete button in an image column. My problem is that my image as an alpha background (.png) and the first data filling creates a white background to my images, anyone knows how to fix it?

My project is a C# Windows form in Visual Studio Code 2019. When I call the filling function again it removes the white background.. Also I'm using the same code to fill it the first time and all the other times after.

Here's some printscreen:

I've opened my program, then added 2 new task and the one that was loaded (task1) as a white bg while the two others got an alpha bg:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyzun.jpg

I've opened my program with these 3 tasks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxpBq.jpg

I've loaded an Empty list then loaded a list of 3 tasks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDFgz.jpg

More info: When I load a new list that contains X Tasks, it won't replace the bg of the X first tasks, seems like the dataGridView needs to be empty in the first place?

Init:

```
    public myApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ComboList(1); // Select my list of task
        int ID = Int32.Parse(comboBox_Lists.SelectedValue.ToString()); // Get the ID of this list
        RefreshData(ID); // Fill the DataGridView with all the tasks linked to the selected list
    }

   public void RefreshThingsList(int ID)
   {
    using (MySqlConnection cnn2 = new MySqlConnection(Globals.connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter commandTasks = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select Item from Tasks where ID_List = " + ID, cnn2))
            {

                // Fill the dataFridView with the selected list of tasks
                DataTable dataSrc = new DataTable(); 
                commandTasks.Fill(dataSrc);

                dataGridViewListThings.DataSource = dataSrc;

                // Resizing my columns: img = 32px / tasks = remaining width + some marging
                DataGridViewColumn column0 = dataGridViewListThings.Columns[0];
                column0.Width = 32;

                DataGridViewColumn column1 = dataGridViewListThings.Columns[1];
                column1.Width = dataGridViewListThings.Width - 41;


            }
        }
    }
```

I expect to have a 100% of the time alpha background for my image column...
Any ideas?

Comment: This depends strongly on the dispaly technology you are using. WinForms? WPF/UWP? ASP.NET? Other? I know for a fact, Windows Forms in particular was terrible with transparency.,

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms :/

Comment: I feared as much. Windows Forms has a very incomplete Transparency support. Transparency was not much of a "thing" when it was developed and it was marked deprecated long before it could be added. What it does do is "draw the parent controls Background color". There are of course workarounds: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window

Comment: Well, some cells look right, other don't, so Winforms fake transparency shouldn't be the culprit..

Comment: Thanks for the information, didnt knew it was working like that. But still, my cells are "ok" and got bg transparency when reloaded. So they should be when first loaded.. I've tried to change the bgColor of the ImageColumn with my main bgColor '''Column1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(71, 71, 71);''' But it doesn't work as well.